# Custom range field based on Hour and time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create a Custom field like below based on below two fields (Hour and Time). Does anyone know how to do this is SQL?

[image]

Comment: Respectfully Sir, I was not able to do it. I am not even sure how to proceed that is the reason I asked here and hoping to get some direction.

Comment: Best find a good tutorial site then and and check out the string and date functions SQL Server provides. Also please don't use images for data - use formatted text. If your data really is stored like that its going to be a pain to convert " Hour 1" to "Hour 0". You'll also want to use `case`.

Comment: Thanks. i will come back with effort.

Comment: I'm a little lost.  Why doesn't the prefix in the custom column match the `hour` column?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the `Hour` column for this result. The `Time` values are enough.

**Sample data**

```
create table data
(
  TimeValue time(0)
);

insert into data (TimeValue) values
('12:00:00 AM'),
('12:15:00 AM'),
('12:30:00 AM'),
('12:45:00 AM'),
( '1:00:00 AM'),
( '1:15:00 AM'),
( '1:30:00 AM'),
( '1:45:00 AM'),
( '2:00:00 AM'),
( '2:15:00 AM'),
( '2:30:00 AM'),
( '2:45:00 AM'),
( '3:00:00 AM'),
( '3:15:00 AM'),
( '3:30:00 AM'),
( '3:45:00 AM'),
( '4:00:00 AM'),
( '4:15:00 AM'),
( '4:30:00 AM');
```

**Solution**

```
select 'Hour ' + convert(nvarchar(2), datepart(hour, d.TimeValue)) as [Hour],
       convert(nvarchar(11), d.TimeValue, 22) as [Time],
       'Hour ' +
       convert(nvarchar(2), case
                               when datepart(hour, d.TimeValue)-1 < 0 then 0
                               else datepart(hour, d.TimeValue)-1
                             end) + '-' +
       convert(nvarchar(2), datepart(hour, d.TimeValue)) as [Custom]
from data d;
```

**Result**

```
Hour    Time         Custom
------  -----------  --------
Hour 0  12:00:00 AM  Hour 0-0
Hour 0  12:15:00 AM  Hour 0-0
Hour 0  12:30:00 AM  Hour 0-0
Hour 0  12:45:00 AM  Hour 0-0
Hour 1   1:00:00 AM  Hour 0-1
Hour 1   1:15:00 AM  Hour 0-1
Hour 1   1:30:00 AM  Hour 0-1
Hour 1   1:45:00 AM  Hour 0-1
Hour 2   2:00:00 AM  Hour 1-2
Hour 2   2:15:00 AM  Hour 1-2
Hour 2   2:30:00 AM  Hour 1-2
Hour 2   2:45:00 AM  Hour 1-2
Hour 3   3:00:00 AM  Hour 2-3
Hour 3   3:15:00 AM  Hour 2-3
Hour 3   3:30:00 AM  Hour 2-3
Hour 3   3:45:00 AM  Hour 2-3
Hour 4   4:00:00 AM  Hour 3-4
Hour 4   4:15:00 AM  Hour 3-4
Hour 4   4:30:00 AM  Hour 3-4
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e65ac173ad376721ddf1661800bbf4ee) to see things in action.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to create a Custom field like below based on below two fields (Hour and Time).

Assuming that you want the column generated from the `hour` column and the "hour" from the `time` column, then you can use a generated column:

```
alter table t add custom as 
    (concat(hour, '-', datepart(hour, time));
```

This is now part of the table.  If you just want the value in a result set, you can put the expression in a result set.

Note:  This doesn't return the results you have specified.  You haven't explained the logic for those results.